# "Continuity" of Integrability?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure: $\mu(X) = \int_X \mu(dx) = 1$.

Consider a locally bounded function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{> 0} \ $  such that:

- $\exists \bar{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\} $ such that: $\int_X f(\bar{z},x) \mu(dx) < \infty  $.

$$ $$

Prove that:

$$ \exists \delta > 0  \text{ s.t. } \ \ ||z-\bar{z}|| < \delta \ \Rightarrow \ \int_X f(z,x) \mu(dx) < \infty $$

Comment: Why should this be true?  You could (say) let $f(0,\cdot)=0$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ for $x \neq 0$ be any bounded function that is not measurable.  Or even if f(x,⋅) is measurable, let it be a random variable with infinite expectation

Comment: maybe I formulated it wrong: $f(x,\cdot)$ is measurable.

I meant the expectation is finite.

Comment: Please edit your post to make clear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  $n=1$, $X = \mathbb R$ with $\mu(dx) = \frac{dx}{\pi (1+x^2)}$, $f(z,x) = (xz)^2$, $\overline{z} = 0$.

Comment: Ok, I need $\bar{z} \neq 0$.

Comment: OK, $f(z,x) = (x(z-1))^2$ and $\overline{z} = 1$.  It's just the same example translated.

Comment: You're right: that's why now I have domain $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Sorry for changing the problem statement... but thanks for helping me in being precise!

Comment: So just add $1$ to $f(z,x)$.  And before you change the problem statement again to avoid this particular example, please think about whether you could modify the example to fit the new rules.